# Ayuda prueba unitaria Java

Tags: java, junit

No tengo claro si se puede implementar una prueba unitaria sobre un método cuyo resultado es variable en el tiempo.

Esta duda parte de que tengo un método que recibe un LocalDate y devuelve un String con la fecha en formato "dd/mm/yyyy".

Para testearlo creó un *LocalDate* con una fecha concreta y luego la vuelvo a obtener, con lo que no hay problema, pero ¿si creo un *LocalDate* para la fecha actual, cómo puedo saber cual es el resultado esperado?

Lo que hice fue crear una segunda implementación del método inicial, internamente diferente pero que recibe lo mismo y produce la misma salida, luego los he testeado de forma cruzada. El problema sería que los dos dieran la misma fecha incorrecta... *Como curiosidad, probé la velocidad de ejecución de las dos implementaciones y parece que la nueva es 6 veces más rápida...*

Comment: Podrías agregar tú código para tener una mejor idea de lo que estás intentando hacer, así será mas fácil ayudar.

Comment: Perdón por la demora, apenas hallé tu pregunta. Espero no te moleste la cátedra de testing :P

Answer (score 0):

> No tengo claro si se puede implementar una prueba unitaria sobre un método cuyo resultado es variable en el tiempo.

Bueno, lo has hecho, así que se puede.

Incluso sin duplicar el algoritmo (luego hablamos sobre eso), podrías hacer la prueba con la fecha actual y tests más simples (no lanza excepción, devuelve un valor que cumple con una expresión regular predeterminada, etc.). Que el String en sí no sea siempre el mismo no significa que no se pueda analizar.

La pregunta es si tiene sentido:

1. Coste: Duplicar el trabajo tiene un coste.
2. Control: Si decides no duplicar el algoritmo (o simplemente no se puede) y haces test más sencillos (por ejemplo el de la expresión regular), te puede pasar por alto errores.
3. No te exime de asegurar la cobertura. Si tienes un caso especial y el 25 de diciembre devuelves "¡Navidad!", deberías pasar un valor con el 25 de diciembre para comprobar que eso sigue funcionando.
4. ¿Para qué? Supongamos que tienes un bug que causa problemas en 2018; hace siete meses compilaste y el test pasó, y ahora compilas y con tu "supertest" lo descubres. Muy bien, pero, ¿si tu tests pasó en 2017, como aseguras que no hay un bug que se manifestará en 2019, no al compilar sino **en producción**? Si el detectar el bug depende del valor de entrada, tu test no es muy bueno.

Con un test unitario deberías asegurarte que pasas suficientes ejemplos como para cubrir todos los posibles "caminos" de ejecución de tu algoritmo (como en el ejemplo de "Navidad", o incluso casos de error como que te pasen un *null*). Una vez hecho esto, si lo has hecho bien, ya tienes un test perfecto.

El mecanismo que propones se usa para el diseño de sistemas críticos (control de un avión, de una central nuclear) donde hay varios sistemas con software diferente **en tiempo de ejecución**, de forma que si uno de ellos empieza a dar valores diferentes se puedan activar mecanismos de control. Pero para un test unitario es excesivo y no te exime de hacer los tests bien para asegurar la cobertura.

Answer (score 0):

Un poco de código sería de gran ayuda para darte una solución que se adapte más fácilmente, así que te daré de la misma manera que tu pregunta, una respuesta con casi nada de código.

Hay muchas formas de crear un `LocalDate` así que en esencia tienes que crearlo por un método estático, lo cual te implica algunos posibles problemitas desde el punto de vista de probar tu aplicación.

Una forma de hacerlo es combinar [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) junto con [powermockito](/questions/tagged/powermockito) que es una extensión a nuestro siempre amado [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito), pero que obviamente nos permite hacer cosas que no son parte del estándard como hacer `mocks` de métodos estáticos como en este caso mediante el método mocks y stubs<sup>1</sup> y agregando convenientemente las dependencias `powermock-module-junit4` y `powermock-api-mockito`.

¿Cómo funciona con la fecha actual?

Simple, la generas tú y haces que la regrese el método estático `LocalDate.now()`, si se trata de un stub siempre regresará la misma `stub(method(LocalDate.class),"now")` y si se trata de un mock `mockStatic` tu le dices que generará.

Si bien esta forma es la más sencilla, como posiblemente habrás notado es debatible el hacer pruebas de este tipo, porque si bien puedes meterle la fecha que quieras realmente no estás tomando algo más real, sino que te estás acomodando la prueba para que funcione como quieres y en realidad te estás enfocando en probar el código de generación de fecha y no tu funcionalidad.

Es decir, como tester normalmente eso implica justificar ante tu desarrollador que ese método debería de ser privado, ya que depende de métodos hechos por alguien más y que si se quiere probar realmente, se debería de hacer la prueba sobre el método que lo llama para evitarse esa mañosidades como usar powermock.

<sup>1</sup> la otra forma de hacerlo sería mediante espías, pero sinceramente no los sé usar en powermock